# Admob for website

Tags: web, admob, dashboard

I want to integrate ads via admob in my website, but I can't choose type website although there seems to be an option for it.

[image: admob]

It says "Select site or app type", but it offers only app types. Admob's dashboard is confusing me in so many ways.

What should I do?

Answer (score 23):

Admob provides ads to mobiles not web sites.
Use Adsense instead. https://www.google.com/adsense

Comment: really?they should update their website to make it clear. thank you

Comment: this used to be the case where you could have websites. I just deleted my old sites and tried adding a new one and BAM!! I guess I should have tried editing instead1!

Comment: @MarianKlühspies the name itself makes it obvious, "AdMob" = "AdMobile".